# Cat dislikes a person who they used to love before

Tags: fear

So my boyfriend and I have a stray cat. She quickly bonded with him and then after 2.5 months she has now become afraid of him but only during the day. At night she jumps up on the bed with him and snuggles, she even bathes him. Does anyone have an idea of what to do or what went wrong.

Edit:
She also will rub against him during dinner and if food is around. So we dont understand what is causing her to he scared

Answer (score 1):

Cats are tricky creatures, and this could be a temporary thing, as long as your boyfriend hasn't been treating the cat any differently.

One thing I've found as a common culprit is scent change - has your boyfriend been using a different cologne, shampoo, or something? I once started wearing a lip moisturizer to bed and my cats stopped sleeping with me because they hated the smell. The fact that your cat likes him at night or in the bath indicates something he could be wearing that has worn off by the end of the day, or is washed off in the bath.

Otherwise, just make sure he keeps treating her well, maybe taking some extra 1:1 time with treats and toys to get her "reacquainted", just as you would with a new cat. Best of luck!